# Google Colab GPU RAM depletes quickly on test data but not so on training data

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory, ram

I am training my neural network built with PyTorch under Google Colab Pro+ (Tesla P100-PCIE GPU) but encounters the following strange phenomenon:

1. The amount of free memory (Mem Free) stays nearly constant when I train the model on training data, so there is no GPU memory issue during training (even over multiple epochs, where I use `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` at the beginning of each epoch).
2. However, Mem Free quickly depletes as soon as I deploy the model on test data after each training epoch. Everything except the input data to the network stays the same during the process.

To be more precise, the code during which Mem Free depletes looks like

```
self.batch_training(train=True)  # no problem
self.batch_training(train=False) # issue occurs,
```

where `self` is a class object which stores the model, data, and the training method.

The function `batch_training` looks like

```
def batch_training(self, train=True):
    if train:
       X, Y = self.X_train, self.Y_train
    else:
       X, Y = self.X_test, self.Y_test
    ...
    (make prediction and does gradient descent if train == True, otherwise, just compute customized losses)
```

Below is a screenshot that illustrates the situation (just ignores the training loss_g and in each batch), where I tried the code on a subset of training data so it moves on to the test data quickly. We can see the issue as soon as Test metrics are computed.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s35tK.png) (sorry could not make it inline due to ''not enough Reputation'')

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might encounter similar issues:

As explained in PyTorch [FAQ](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html),

> Don’t accumulate history across your training loop. By default, computations involving variables that require gradients will keep history. This means that you should avoid using such variables in computations which will live beyond your training loops, e.g., when tracking statistics. Instead, you should detach the variable or access its underlying data.

In my case, adding `with torch.no_grad()` before my `self.batch_training(train=False)` resolves the issue.